# Infragistics Error,, Please anyone help me out on this

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing this error since yesterday and looked over internet but couldn't find any solutions. If any one else has ever faced this too, please tell me how to fix this.

> Error  11  Unable to resolve type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinChart.UltraChart, Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinChart.v11.1, Version=11.1.20071.1067, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'    D:\Farrukh\FMSChawla\AP_ERP\SupremeFarms_FMS\Properties\licenses.licx   1   SupremeFarms_FMS

Comment: What is the code causing this error?

Comment: Still using Infragistics2? Are you sure that you need this assembly instead of Infragistcs4?

Comment: well it is used in the application im workin on, so had to..

Comment: If you try Add Reference... dialog and search for the Infragists2.Win.UltraWinChart do you see the version required? If yes try to readd it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference to a dll that  isn't installed in your computer. If they're unused, edit licenses.licx file into myproject directory, and delete that line. Maybe that project was created on a computer with the infragistics components installed, and you don't have them in your computer.